# Android: Overlapping makes list buggy

Tags: java, android, listview, drawable, overlap

I have a custom listview and made overlapping very simple: in `onDraw` method, I set rows' z axis to about 200 and I override `getChildDrawingOrder (int childCount, int i)`. So the result looks like this:

[image]

Of course, there are more transitions to look like that, but they are not related to this  question.

But as you see, for about a second, the top row (i mean in z axis, which is white) looks buggy. There are `imageViews` with two state drawable (white when row is in center and blue when outside center) by coordinates. Change drawables programatically by setting background drawable. Bug seems to show when happens transition from one drawable to another: redrawing of bottom piece happens later than main piece of row. I need to make both pieces to change drawables at same time, so there won't be such bugs. Is it android's bug or can I solve it?

Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: When you're changing the drawing order you could call invalidate or requestlayout on the changing z-order views. Maybe check how the Gallery view is implemented.

Comment: requestLayout() works! it uses more resources, but i am trying to implement it where it touch performance less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used nininho suggestion to apply requestLayout() in `rotected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, final View child, long drawingTime) {}` method end and it works.

P.S. put it where you really need it, I put it where goes transitions only, because this method eats lots of resources, while it repaints whole child.

Answer (score 0):

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

in your listview. Give it a try.

regards,

Fabian